# Project / reduce an array with nested arrays to a given format

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, treeview

I am struggling to find a way to project/reduce an array based on a format to display an Angular Material tree-view. The structure of the data I have is the one below:

```js
let data = [
  {
    section_name: "section one",
    blocks: [
      {
        block_name: "block one"
      },
      {
        block_name: "block two"
      }
    ],
    sections: []
  },
  {
    section_name: "section two",
    blocks: [
      {
        block_name: "block three"
      }
    ],
    sections: [
      {
        section_name: "subsection1",
        blocks: [
          {
            block_name: "subsection1 block1"
          }
        ],
        sections: []
      },
      {
        section_name: "subsection2",
        blocks: [
          {
            block_name: "subsection2 block1",
          },
          {
            block_name: "subsection2 block2",
          }
        ],
        sections: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It should be shaped in the format below. So basically every outer object in the array above is a section, and each section might have blocks and subsections. Each block name must be inserted in the children array as an object with the name property, but for the subsections we need to check if there are other nested subsections (recursively).

```js
[
  {
    "name": "section one",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "block one"
      },
      {
        "name": "block two"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "section two",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "block three"
      },
      {
        "name": "subsection1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "subsection1 block1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "subsection2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "subsection2 block1"
          },
          {
            "name": "subsection2 block2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: The expected output has a problem. There would be two same key ```name``` and ```children``` in an object. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes I apologize it was my bad. I have fixed the output object.

Comment: I would suggest that both the input and output would be easier to read here in the question if you replaced the three-line single-property objects with one-liners such as `{ block_name: "subsection2 block1"}` and `{ name: "subsection2 block1" }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be managed with a fairly simple recursion.  The only complexity is that you want to combine the results of processing `blocks` and the result of processing `sections` into a single `children` node.  We just do this by spreading the results of each into a single array:

```js
const convert = (records) =>
  records .map (({section_name, blocks, sections}) => ({
    name: section_name,
    children: [
      ... blocks .map (({block_name}) => ({name: block_name})),
      ... convert (sections)
    ]
  }))

const data = [{section_name: "section one", blocks: [{block_name: "block one"}, {block_name: "block two"}], sections: []}, {section_name: "section two", blocks: [{block_name: "block three"}], sections: [{section_name: "subsection1", blocks: [{block_name: "subsection1 block1"}], sections: []}, {section_name: "subsection2", blocks: [{block_name: "subsection2 block1"}, {block_name: "subsection2 block2"}], sections: []}]}]

console .log (convert (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```